# Integrating LUIS with FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, formflow

I have created a bot, having a FormFlow in it. Now if you type I want to launch a product, LUIS will tell which dialog it has to go to :

```
    internal static IDialog<AssesmentHelper> CreateProduct()
            {
                return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(AssesmentHelper.BuildForm))
                    .Do(async (context, profileForm) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var completed = await profileForm;

                        }
                        catch (FormCanceledException<AssesmentHelper> e)
                        {
                            string reply;
                            if (e.InnerException == null)
                            {
                                reply = $"You quit on {e.Last}--maybe you can finish next time!";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                reply = Responses.ShortCircuit;
                            }
                            await context.PostAsync(reply);
                        }
                    });
            }

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        { 
stLuis = await LuisHelper.ParseUserInput(activity.Text);
    switch (stLuis.topScoringIntent.intent)
    {

         case "CreateProduct":
              await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, CreateProduct);
              break;

         case "EditProduct":
               await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, EditProduct);
               break;

           case "None":

               break;

            default:
               break;
    }
}
```

Now, once it enters dialog, it asks user to select numbers:

Please select numbers:

1. Azure
2. Windows

Now if I reply 1,2. Luis returns it as None intent, so my message does not go to the corresponding dialog. It always go to None case.

The code for dialog is:

```
 public static IForm<AssesmentHelper> BuildForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<AssesmentHelper>()
                    .Message(Responses.NumberSelection)
                    .Field(nameof(Program))
                    .Field(nameof(Product))
                    .Build();
        }
```

Enum for program and product:

```
[Serializable]
    public enum Program
    {
        None = 0,
        A = 1,
     };

        [Serializable]
        public enum Product
        {
            None = 0,
            Azure = 1,
            Windows = 2
        };
```

As soon as I enter this dialog, It asks me to select number for selecting program. Now if i select 1,2. Luis returns it as None intent. So Case "None", is executed.

What I want is, redirect the control to same dialog. I have similar dialog for Edit Product as well. That's why I cannot train my luis app to understand numbers as Product Intent. Otherwise whenever i select number for Edit Product, it will go to different case.

Earlier it was identifying correct intents somehow, but today i republished my luis app and it stopped identifying.

Comment: Luis cannot infer an intent for a number, but during "none" processing you can parse `activity.Text` to see if the message is a number, and if so handle it accordingly.

Comment: What if other dialog also have number as input, then how to decide which dialog to go for.

Comment: That's what conversation state is for: you need to know what you asked so you can correctly  process the answer.

Comment: can you post the code of your CreateDialog for example? or the dialog that is prompting the user for the numbers?

Comment: updated the code above @EzequielJadib

Comment: I assume your dialog is calling in the StartAsync your form? Can you post the complete dialog?

Instead of Conversation.SendAsync, can you try using context.Forward?.The first parameter is the instance of the dialog, the second the resume callback, and then the message to forward (just do context.MakeMessage in your case) and then a CancellationToken. Also make sure you are using the latest version of the builder.

Comment: @EzequielJadib I have update my dialog method. I didn't understand what you said about context.MakeMessage. I hope my requirement is clear.

Comment: I see... is there any reason why you are not using Dialogs and a LuisDialog. Why you are using Chain?