# BotFramework Step by step questions where each dialog has an assigned LUIS intent

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a step by step question to the user where each question is a dialog. Can I have a step by step flow and each having a different LUIS Intent? What is the best approach for this?

What I want is:
[image]

I’m not sure how to assign one intent per dialog because when in `RoomReservationDialog` I just instantiate the dialog for the first step which is `RoomReservationNameDialog`. Then inside `RoomReservationNameDialog` I just instantiate the next step which is `RoomReservationDateTimeDialog` in the MessageReceived method.

```
class RoomReservationDialog
{
    protected override async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
            {
                context.Call(new RoomReservationNameDialog(), MessageReceived);
            }

}

class RoomReservationNameDialog
{
    public override async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        // ask question
    }

    protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
            {
                 …
                 context.Call(new RoomReservationDateTimeDialog(), HandleResult);
            }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain your use case here, Why do you want a dialog for each intent rather than having all your intents in one dialog?

Comment: @JasonSowers, it is because of the step by step nature of asking for information. Basically, when the user is answering what room name we only want LUIS to get the intent and entity specific to Room.AnswerName. If the user, for example, answers a date when asking for room name we don't want LUIS to process it as Room.AnswerDateTime because that is a different step.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, people put their intents in the same dialog like the code below.  From this dialog, you can call another one inside the intent if that is how you want to structure your code.

```
[Serializable]
[LuisModel("Luis app id", "Luis key")]
public class LuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string message = $"Sorry, I did not understand '{result.Query}'. Type 'help' if you need assistance.";
        await context.PostAsync(message);
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("greeting")]
    public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string message = $"Hello there";
        await context.PostAsync(message);
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }
    [LuisIntent("Room.AnswerName")]
    public async Task Left(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        //do stuff 
        //or call new dialog to do stuff
        context.Call(new RoomReservationNameDialog(), ResumeAfterMethod);
    }
    [LuisIntent("Room.AnswerDateTime")]
    public async Task Right(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        //do stuff 
        //or call new dialog to do stuff
        context.Call(new RoomReservationDateTimeDialog(), ResumeAfterMethod);
    }
    [LuisIntent("Room.AnswerFloor")]
    public async Task Middle(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        //do stuff 
        //or call new dialog to do stuff
        context.Call(new RoomReservationFloorDialog(), ResumeAfterMethod);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is how it is mostly structured. For our scenario though we want first for them to go to the "reserve room" intent instead of saying something that might trigger the other intents first like Room.AnswerDateTime. For example if the user goes to the chatbot and says they want a room given a date it might go to Room.AnswerDateTime first. Our steps are actually more complex than this and the room reservation is just a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at FormFlow ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow))? It seems like a suitable answer to your step-by-step flow.

Also specifically using FormFlow with LUIS, you can look at this previously asked question ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610686/integrating-luis-with-formflow)) and this recent [blog post](https://www.suneco.nl/blogs/sitecore-and-microsoft-bot-framework-luis-model-and-formflow) that might help.